# Storing type fields in a list

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Hello i am faced with the following problem. I have a data type with multiple fields.I need to enumerate them and store them in a collection for further mapping.

```
data Worker=Worker{
        age::Int,
        name::String,
        title::Title,
        income::Int
    }


    data Title=Manager | Dev | Tester deriving (Show)



    instance Show Worker where 
        show w=let !names=["age","name", "title","income"] 
                   !props= [age,name,title,income]  in   -- Do i need to define another new type to be able to flat them down to a list?
            "{"++intercalate "," (zipWith (\x y-> x++":"++ y w) names props)++"}"
```

Where can i store all all properties (methods)to be able to further use them as a parameter in a higher order function on a given variable of type `Worker` in our case.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. [More examples and discussion here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Well i am asking if there is a better way.

Comment: You ask, "What's a better way to do Y?". I ask, "If you could do Y, what X does that help you achieve? Perhaps instead of doing Y at all, there is a better way to do X in the first place that doesn't involve Y.".

Comment: Don't use `Show` to generate a JSON object; use an actual JSON library.

Comment: Use this library: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.16/aeson-1.2.4.0/Data-Aeson.html

Comment: Apologies: I completely missed the `instance Show Worker` code block. That is presumably the answer to my objection about XY problems. Great!

Comment: No need ,  but i was really banging by head with  what was wrong with my question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get sort of close to the thing you're looking for, but it's not going to be pretty.

We can use `RecordWildCards` to bring all of the accessor names into scope as though they were ordinary variables, but that still introduces a new problem.

```
-- Not runnable Haskell code
foo Worker {..} = let names = ["age", "name", "title", "income"]
                      props = [age, name, title, income]
                  in ...
```

We're pattern matching on `Worker {..}`, which introduces a bunch of accessor names into the local scope. However, `props` is trying to be a heterogeneous list, which Haskell does not allow. It contains two integers, a string, and a title, whereas Haskell lists are only supposed to contain one type.

Since you're trying to show each field, you're going to have to apply `show` to *each* element by hand. Like I said, this is going to be a bit ugly.

```
foo Worker {..} = let names = ["age", "name", "title", "income"]
                      props = [show age, show name, show title, show income]
                  in ...
```

It may look like we can do `map show [age, name, title, income]`, but we can't. That list still wouldn't be valid, and we're applying three different `show` functions here (they just happen to share a name), so we can't meaningfully map the *same* `show` over each element.

However, as the comments say, your best bet is to familiarize yourself with a proper JSON library, and Aeson is easily the best choice in Haskell for that sort of thing.